# Firestore Backup Stuck in Creating State

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, gcloud

I created a firestore backup job [following this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/backups#create_a_daily_backup_schedule). I have been waiting for about 3 hours and every time I check the status of the job, it says the STATE is CREATING. I feel like it should not take this long. It is a large database but not that large.

```
gcloud alpha firestore backups list --format="table(name, database, state)"
NAME                        DATABASE                                    STATE
projects/<project-id>/...   projects/<project-id>/databases/(default)   CREATING
```

Should I delete the backup schedule? I really don't want to mess anything up in this project.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the state says READY. The entire thing probably took 6 or 7 hours.

I think I will try [point in time recovery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pitr) instead. IDK if there is a benefit to using one over the other.